# How to connect points on a 3D plot using ax.scatter and ax.plot in Numpy?

Tags: python, plot, scatter-plot

I have to make a 3D plot with multiple parallel line plots. I can put the points (for three lines) on plot using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

ax = plt.gca(projection ='3d')

ax.scatter(0, 0, 100, color = 'red')
ax.scatter(0,1,128, color = 'red')
ax.scatter(0,2,30, color = 'red')
ax.scatter(0,3,15, color = 'red')

ax.scatter(1, 0, 100, color = 'blue')
ax.scatter(1, 1, 45, color = 'blue')
ax.scatter(1,2,13, color = 'blue')
ax.scatter(1,3,6, color = 'blue')

ax.scatter(2, 0, 100, color = 'green')
ax.scatter(2, 1, 55, color = 'green')
ax.scatter(2, 2, 27, color = 'green')
ax.scatter(2, 3, 26, color = 'green')

plt.show()
```

And the result is following:
[image]

Now I'm stuck with connection of these points with a line (red points with red line, blue points with blue line etc.). I think this can be done with `ax.plot`?

I want to get a 3D plot containing the points connected with segments.

I tried to connect points via:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

ax = plt.gca(projection ='3d')

p1,p2,p3,p4 = [0,0,100],[0,1,128],[0,2,30],[0,3,15]
ax.scatter(p1,p2,p3,p4, c='r',s=10)
ax.plot(p1,p2,p3,p4, color='r')

plt.show()
```

and I received a nonsense:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The arguments to `ax.plot()` should not be the individual points, but the individual dimensions: first a list of all the x-values, then all the y-values, and then all the z-values. You can use the same syntax for `ax.scatter()`.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

data = {'red': ([0] * 4,
                range(4),
                [100, 128, 30, 15]),
        'blue': ([1] * 4,
                 range(4),
                 [100, 45, 13, 6]),
        'green': ([2] * 4,
                  range(4),
                  [100, 55, 27, 26])}

ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

for color, points in data.items():
    ax.scatter(*points, color=color)
    ax.plot(*points, color=color)

plt.show()
```

[image: Line plot in 3d]

However, the fact that these lines lie in parallel planes strongly suggests that you don't actually need a 3-dimensional plot. The third dimension is already encoded by the colors, so the 2-dimensional plot loses no information while making it much easier to compare the lines.

```py
data = {'red': (range(4),
                [100, 128, 30, 15]),
        'blue': (range(4),
                 [100, 45, 13, 6]),
        'green': (range(4),
                  [100, 55, 27, 26])}

ax = plt.axes()

for color, points in data.items():
    ax.scatter(*points, color=color)
    ax.plot(*points, color=color)

plt.show()
```

[image: Line plot in 2d]